# Bootstrap multiple modal dismiss all with the last modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, popup, modal-dialog

How can i create multiple overlapping modal popups, and dismiss all the modals with the close button (data-dismiss) on the last modal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create multiple modals, that will naturally overlap each other based on the order they were clicked in. Then, on whatever modal you want to be able to close all modals, you can use this, adjusting it to your liking:

```
$('.modal').modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

Stacking modals isn't supported out-of-the-box in Bootstrap, you'll need to fiddle with the JS (& possibly CSS) yourself:

> ### [Overlapping modals not supported](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)
>
> Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code.